# Whats causing misalignment with submit button and button

Tags: html, css

I have HTML like ...

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
<button name="forgotPassword" id="forgotPassword" type="button" class="linkButton">Forgot Password</button>
```

CSS looks like

```
input[type=button], input[type=submit], button {
  border: none;
  background: $mainColor;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=button]:hover, input[type=button]:active,
input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=submit]:active,
button:hover, button:active {
  background: $hoverColor;
}
```

But my buttons seem misaligned ... forgot password is alittle higher ... How can I fix this (align them vertically)?

[image]

Comment: Did you check in different browsers, on firefox looks okey.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `<input type="button">` instead of `<button>`?

Comment: I am afraid this is the neatest and most consistent answer. Besides, AFAIK, IE6 and lower do not know what the `<button>` tag is supposed to do.

Comment: Whichever form of button he wants to use is fine by me. But it's crazy to mix and match like that, **especially** when you're trying to figure out why one button looks slightly different.

Comment: IE7 does know `<button>` it just submits them all when one is pressed, you have to add a stupid hack to make IE7 behave itself: http://www.kopz.org/public/documents/css/multiple_buttons_ie_workaround.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height attribut of the login button a bit highter in IE. But aligned okey in forfox.

```
input[type=button], input[type=submit], button {
  border: none;
  background: $mainColor;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
input[type=button]:hover, input[type=button]:active,
input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=submit]:active,
button:hover, button:active {
  background: $hoverColor;
  height:50px;
}
```